# Structuring multiple data in a matrix

Tags: r, reshape

I searched to structure my data, but I was unsuccessful. Sorry, if I missed something during searching.

Here is my data

```
id  M1  M2  M3  Q1  Q2  Q3
1   12  13  14  A   B   C
2   13  10  15  D   D   E
3   16  2   16  C   B   A
4   19  11  11  D   A   C
5   9   0   10  B   A   D
```

I want to see it as follows:

```
ID  M   Q   V
1   M1  A   12
1   M2  B   13
1   M3  C   14
2   M1  D   13
2   M2  D   10
2   M3  E   15
3   M1  C   16
3   M2  B   2
3   M3  A   16
4   M1  D   19
4   M2  A   11
4   M3  C   11
5   M1  B   9
5   M2  A   0
5   M3  D   10
```

Is there a simple approach? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way that uses the `reshape2` library that might suit you. First, melt the data once for each subset of variables (the "M"s and "Q"s). Bind them into a single data frame, then finish up by reordering them.

```
M<-melt(mat, id.vars = "id", 
        measure.vars = c("M1","M2","M3"), 
        variable.name = "M", value.name = "V", )

Q<- melt(mat, id.vars = "id", 
         measure.vars = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), 
         value.name = "Q")[,3]

bound<- cbind(M, Q)
final <- bound[order(bound$id),][,c(1,2,4,3)]

> final
   id  M Q  V
1   1 M1 A 12
6   1 M2 B 13
11  1 M3 C 14
2   2 M1 D 13
7   2 M2 D 10
12  2 M3 E 15
3   3 M1 C 16
8   3 M2 B  2
13  3 M3 A 16
4   4 M1 D 19
9   4 M2 A 11
14  4 M3 C 11
5   5 M1 B  9
10  5 M2 A  0
15  5 M3 D 10
```

Comment: You bet. It was really just skipping a step. If you run the code without the `[,3]`, you will see that the code `Q<- melt(...   ..."Q")` returns a data frame with three columns. By using `[,3]` to subset that data frame, only the third column (the one with the "A,B,C,D,E" values) is kept.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. You *would* need to change your measured variables code though, to something like `... measure.vars = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6"), ...` (and same for M values). However, since `melt` would put all of those into a single column, you should be fine to leave the `[,3]`, as long as nothing else has changed. You should see what I mean if you look at `print(M)`- there are three columns, but only one column (column 2 in that case) contains M values.